# Xcode is too slow to edit on a large project

Tags: swift, xcode, performance, edit

Summary:
I have a large Xcode project 50 + scenes with some files with a large number of lines. I have separated the scenes into 15 different story boards. Currently it takes 5 minutes to switch to see the compiler errors/warnings. There are approximately 100 swift files in the project. When I am trying to edit a swift file , the editor hangs and the spinning "beachball" appears for minutes. I have deadlines to finish and editing is just impossible...I have tried clearing derived data and clearing caches...cleaning and restarting. This worked for a while but now makes no difference. I appreciate your help.

I have read that certain coding can affect the parsing during editing. How do I find which bit of my code is at fault?

it is taking me minutes to make a change to a parameter

Version/Build:
 I have installed Xcode 9, although I was having similar problems with Xcode 8

Configuration:
I am using a MacBook pro model a1706. 8 gig of Ram, 2.9ghz processor.

Comment: Please check your hard disk space, you may want to clear out derived data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really think there is anything you can do. In my experience storyboards always massively slow down a project which is why I always personally use individual nibs instead of storyboards. I would suggest that in the future but I don't think there is anything you can do now

Comment: Either your mac is running out of SSD disk space or you have an application that eats out the CPU. Check available disk space and check Activity Monitor for  suspicious CPU usage.

Comment: Hi, I have 27gig free out of 191 Gig...clearing derived data helped for around a month...but is not working anymore. I made changes so I am going back to a earlier version to see if it was the code I added....very frustrating

Comment: when the beach ball is spinning, Xcode is using  100% of the cpu

Answer (score 22):

The following resolved most Xcode 9 beachball issues for me, and perhaps it will help someone else...

Quit Xcode.
From the Finder, right-click your project (.xcodeproj) file.
Choose "Show Package Contents".
Right-click the "project.xcworkspace" item.
Choose "Show Package Contents".
Open the "xcuserdata" folder, then the ".xcuserdata" folder.
Drag the "UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate" item to the desktop (just in case).
Delete the "UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate" item.
Launch Xcode and open your project.

This resulted in a dramatic performance increase when opening and navigating my large objective-c project (which has 250 xib files, and over 100 source code files).  Of course, YMMV.

Comment: My Xcode 10 editor was too slow and was killing me. Although it was building fine on simulator. No issues on simulator and compiling the project but just the code editor was very slow. This fixed the problem. And everything is working fine like code completion etc.

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: I wasn't expecting it.... but it worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Worked on Xcode 13 like a char. Thank you

Comment: for xcode 13, this file located at .xcworkspace -> xcuserdata -> <userName>.xcuserdata.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer years ago. Years later, I'm now using Xcode 15 and it still works like a charm. (Super loud fan => silence and peace)

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 13, in a project that uses Pods, open right click in .xcworkspace, and select "Show Package Contents". Open xcuserdata and then open .xcuserdatad. Find the file UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate and delete it.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this fixed works for me in XCOde 13.1 -- was suffering with slow editing, UE response, etc. for weeks and couldn't find a working fix (until I read your post).

Comment: @JoeRosen you can express that "+1" in the form of an upvote :)